# How to create an array of objects in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to the react world. I am trying to write a code in which when an icon is pressed the Image is added into a favourite category and then on the favourite page the image should be displayed. I am having an issue with not knowing how to dynamically get the value out of the image and add them to favourite category without loosing the pervious value. I think the way I wrote states seems messed up. I write in typescript and use material UI

**SearchResults**

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
const [favImage, setFavImage] = useState<ImageProps>({
    id: '',
    farm: 0,
    server: '',
    secret: '',
    title: ''
});

const handleFavImage = ({ farm, server, id, secret, title }: ImageProps): void => {
    setFavImage({ id, farm, server, secret, title });
};
```

**ImageModal**

```
const handleFavourite = (): void => {
    setIcon(!icon);
    if (!icon === true && handleFavImage !== undefined) {
        handleFavImage({ farm, server, id, secret, title });
    }
};
```

Comment: Instead of sharing your entire application, try to drastically reduce the code so it's *just* enough for someone on this site to see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Image Id as reference.

Use redux store / local storage to store the fav image Ids.

Assuming you have all the images here:

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

On click of the Icon, pass Image Id of the selected Image and iterate through the `images` array to find the image props.

just to make you understand how to use the component state array do to this operation:

Lets create a state which will store fav image ids

```
const [favImages, setFavImages] = useState([]);
```

On Click will look something like this

```
const handleOnClick = (imageId) => {
    var arr = [...favImages]; //copy array by value
    arr.push(imageId)
    setFavImages(arr) //override state with new values
}
```

Now the `favImages` array has the list of fav image ids.

Now, use this `favImages` in your `favourite page` component.

```
let favImageProps = props.images.filter(image => props.favImages.indexOf(image.id) !== -1)
```

Comment: I got it fixed thanks to your answer. I was restricted from using var and let. So I had to make changes without them

Answer (score 0):

I had the restriction for not using var and let in the code. So I had to change the code.

```
    const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
    const [favImage, setFavImage] = useState<ImageProps[]>([]);
    const handleFavImage = ({ farm, server, id, secret, title }: ImageProps): void => {
        setFavImage([...favImage, { id, farm, server, secret, title }]);
    };
```